# Typescript: How can a class extend the same interface as its base class with different type parameters?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to allow two classes to extend the same interface, but with a different type parameter. I have SomeTypedInterface, SomeClass which extends SomeBaseClass, and ISomeProps which extends ISomeBaseProps. I want SomeClass and SomeBaseClass to both extend SomeTypedInterface with their respective props.

Note: Neither class actually implements SomeTypedInterface or ISome*Props. There is some automagic stuff happening behind the scenes that is not super relevant to this question. Long story short, the function in SomeTypedInterface and the properties in ISome*Props will be added to instances of these classes automatically. I'm just trying to make the compiler aware of the types in play here so that we have good intellisense when working with these objects.

Here's the simple example in question:

```
interface SomeTypedInterface<TProps>
{
    getProps(): TProps;
}

interface ISomeBaseClassProps
{
    baseStringProp: string;
}

interface SomeBaseClass extends ISomeBaseClassProps,
    SomeTypedInterface<ISomeBaseClassProps> { }
class SomeBaseClass
{
    ...
}

interface ISomeClassProps extends ISomeBaseClassProps
{
    booleanProp: boolean;
}

interface SomeClass extends ISomeClassProps,
    SomeTypedInterface<ISomeClassProps> { }
class SomeClass extends SomeBaseClass
{
    ...
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
Interface 'SomeClass' cannot simultaneously extend types 'SomeBaseClass' and 'SomeTypedInterface<ISomeClassProps>'.
Named property 'getProps' of types 'SomeBaseClass' and 'SomeTypedInterface<ISomeClassProps>' are not identical.
```

Some other info:

1. We need this to be as simple as possible for the consuming class to implement - SomeTypedInterface is actually quite complex so proper declaration merging is a non-starter
2. It's possible that the base class will not actually be defined in TypeScript, but exist purely has the set of automatically added functions and properties that are being specified in those interfaces.
3. The I*Props interface passed to SomeTypedInterface when defining a class will always extend the I*Props interface of the base class.

What I'm really looking for is a way to tell the compiler that SomeClass' extension of SomeTypedInterface overrides SomeBaseClass' extension of that same interface, with a (simple or complex) change to SomeTypedInterface and/or a simple change to the class' interfaces. This is going to be a widely used pattern so simplicity in individual implementation is critical.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I have found a solution that I am okay with.

Instead of having the base class and the derived class both extend the interface, I have the base class accept a generic type and then extend the interface with the combined types of its own props and the generic type. The derived class then just extends the base class.

The result is that both classes do extend the interface with a different type parameter.

```
interface SomeTypedInterface<TProps>
{
    getKeys(): keyof TProps;
}

interface ISomeBaseClassProps
{
    baseStringProp: string;
}

interface SomeBaseClass<TProps extends ISomeBaseClassProps = ISomeBaseClassProps> extends ISomeBaseClassProps,
    SomeTypedInterface<TProps & ISomeBaseClassProps> { }
class SomeBaseClass<TProps>
{
    ...
}

interface ISomeClassProps extends ISomeBaseClassProps
{
    booleanProp: boolean;
}

interface SomeClass extends ISomeClassProps { }
class SomeClass extends SomeBaseClass<ISomeClassProps>
{
    ...
}
```

There are two downsides to this solution, but both are acceptable for my use case, I think.

1. Intellisense isn't perfect when it comes to generic types. When in the base class, it shows the return value of getKeys() as `keyof TProps | "baseStringProp`. It works perfectly in the derived class since that class takes no generics.
2. The class declaration is a little more confusing.

In our scenario, a good portion of the "classes" we're working with won't actually need a class declaration (#2 in the "Some other info" section of the question), so I think that this is an acceptable (though certainly not ideal) workaround for the less common case of multiple-level inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of (or in addition to) declaration merging you can actually declare the properties in the classes?  Like:

```
class SomeClass extends SomeBaseClass {
  getProps!: () => ISomeClassProps;  // note the !
}
```

The actual implementation can be done with whatever magic you did before, but now `SomeClass` stops complaining about the type of `getProps`.  Note the [definite assignment assertion (`!`)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#definite-assignment-assertions) so that `--strictPropertyInitialization` doesn't bother you.

Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately, SomeTypedInterface is actually significantly more complex and declaring each member of it in the extending classes is a non-starter. All of the auto-functionality is added to even the simplest classes and we need to make it as simple as possible for someone making a new class to extend that functionality.

Comment: Hmm, I think this answers the question as asked; if you have additional constraints, could you edit your question to include them?

Comment: I've added a different answer which uses a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach, assuming you need programmatic creation of the class properties and can't add them manually.  Let's make a helper function which returns the `SomeBaseClass` constructor and asserts it to be a narrower type.  Then you can have your subclasses extend the return value of that function, and it should have a similar effect as declaration merging:

```
// helper function asserting that SomeBaseClass returns instances of a narrower type T
const assertSomeBaseClass = <T extends SomeBaseClass>() => SomeBaseClass as (new () => T);

// don't do declaration merging, instead extend an asserted-to-be-narrower class:
class SomeClass extends assertSomeBaseClass<
  ISomeClassProps & SomeTypedInterface<ISomeClassProps>
>() {
  //...
}

// test the properties
declare const someClass: SomeClass;
someClass.baseStringProp; // string
someClass.booleanProp; // boolean
someClass.getProps(); // ISomeClassProps
```

That seems to work, at least given what I know about your use case.  Hope that helps.  Good luck again!

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but it doesn't appear to allow for real class extension. If there are any members on SomeBaseClass, then the compiler complains that SomeClass doesn't contain those members. I think this solution also fails the "simple" test. I've updated the question to have a better explanation of what kind of solution I'm looking for (if it's even possible). Thanks for the suggestions!